# How to list all H and P statements in chemistry in the appendix?

Tags: chemmacros

I am a chemistry student want to list all H and P statements in the appendix of my lab report. To write an H statement individually, I use the package *chemmacros* and the command `\ghs{h}{290}` for H statement phrase 290 and `\ghs{P}{280}` for P statement phrase 280. I want to list them all in my appendix, but without having to write every single statement.

Does anyone know a command or a package for this problem?

Comment: See section 7 _List of All Statements_ of the `ghsystem` manual where the command `\ghslistall` is described

Comment: Or do you mean all statements _used_ in the document before? The package does not prove a functionality for this

Comment: No I meant ALL statements. Thanks, you just saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ghsystem` package from the `chemmacros` bundle provides a command `\ghslistall` which creates a table (with `longtable`) that contains all H and P statements. The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ghsystem}
\begin{document}
\ghslistall
\end{document}
```

prints the 8.5 pages long table. There are a number of possible customizations which are all described in 7 *List of All Statements* of the `ghsystem` manual.